# .htaccess redirect any subdomain *.domain1.com to *.domain2.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect every subdomains of domain1.com to domain2.com

```
foo.domain1.com -> foo.domain2.com

baz.domain1.com -> baz.domain2.com

bar.domain1.com -> bar.domain2.com

etc
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046069/2024688

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%2.domain2.com/$1  [L,R]
```