# UrlRewrite and subdomains (foo.domain1.com to foo.domain2.com

Tags: java, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to adapt the following Apache mod_rewrite rules to work with [UrlRewrite](http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/) - foo.domain1.com to foo.domain2.com like the following post.  I wish we could just put Apache in front of Tomcat and make it simple.

[.htaccess redirect any subdomain *.domain1.com to *.domain2.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141021/htaccess-redirect-any-subdomain-domain1-com-to-domain2-com)

[Advanced HTACCESS Subdomain Redirection (foo.dom2.com to foo.dom1.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045603/advanced-htaccess-subdomain-redirection-foo-dom2-com-to-foo-dom1-com)

Unfortunately, the following does not redirect to the subdomain, simply to .domain2.com or with %1%2 in front of .domain2.com

Further more when I go directly to foo.domain2.com it also redirects to the aforementioned bad result.

```
<condition name="host" operator="notequal">^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain1\.net$</condition>
<condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
<from>^</from>
<to type="redirect" last="true">http://%1%2.domain2.com</to>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "%1%2" with "$1$2".